# Need Container, the keys known from the start but the value don't

Tags: c++, containers

I want to use container like unordered map, but i have two special requirements...

- I know from the start all the keys can be, so i want to first enter all the keys without the values.
- After the keys entered, and the program continue, i want to know which value was filled already, **but not with const value like '0' etc., and not with pointers.**

thank you, and sorry about my poor English

Comment: If you can't use pointers, how about if the values are `std::pair`s with a bool telling you if it's a valid value?

Comment: Why would you need to pre-fill all the keys? Maybe there's a better way to design your solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::unordered_map<key_type,boost::optional<value_type>>
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html